# How to make outlined speechbubble with layer-list?

Tags: android, drawable, layer-list

I have some type of chat in my app and want to achieve, to have and outlined speech-bubble as background for my messages.

I´ve already created a shape, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drQuK.png), but i cant achieve, to have this real chat-speech-bubble-shape like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Nzn.png) (i painted this with windows paint program).

So my question: Is there wa way to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Nzn.png) shape as outlined drawable xml file, and if so, can anyone help me? I´ve found just the shapes: line, oval, rectangle. Can we create with these [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Nzn.png) an speechbubble. Here´s the code for my xml drawable (without speechbubble-shape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="7dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Comment: I think you should use 9patch https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Comment: You can also search online for icons that you can use. I suggest [flaticon](http://flaticon.com)